# How to align text left inside a button, which is inside a centre widget | Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

my buttons are must be on center but must aligned in same line ,
the text in side button also should aligned left.
for that i use textalign left but not works in my code , I dont know why.[This is my layout screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1kmz.png)

So Can anyone modify my code so that the text inside button aligned left ,without affecting my buttons position .

Thank you

```
class Something extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Solve Before Downvote !'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Color(0xff263238),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('SomeThing', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () { },
                      child: Text('Nothing', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Can You do something ?',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    ),
                    MaterialButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('Nothing to do !', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[what i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1kmz.png)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for but the `MaterialButton` has a default `padding` which can be removed by using `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` in your `MaterialButton`.

Comment: I asked about the text inside the Material button , should be align left . for that i use textAlign: TextAlign.left but not working , You can see in screenshot.

Comment: That is because of the default `padding` the `MaterialButton` has, you can remove the `padding` by setting it to `EdgeInsets.zero`.

Comment: Do you need all button in center align vertically and horozontaly?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/W2pF5nP/image.png ->image 1 or https://i.ibb.co/hZ60zYt/image.png =>image 2which one you meant

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/W2pF5nP/image.png this one

Comment: @evan I need all Buttons are in center but their starting points are must be in same line , you can see screenshot

Comment: @void, change the padding to zero but it doesnot align my text to left.

Comment: @PMahto, center can be both side, horozontal vertical, so i starting point from top or left? I attached 2 picture, can you tell me is those? or what you mean by center and starting point

Comment: @evan I need this https://i.ibb.co/W2pF5nP/image.png

Comment: you need to use `GestureDetector` for this, is it ok? Answer posted. PLease check it.

Comment: @evan, I never tried GestureDetector till let me try !, are you tried GestureDetecton in my cade ?

Comment: Ok, yes, i just edit it. If you wanna check, than i have edited the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below code. I have comment out the solution in code.

```
class Something extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('Solve Before Downvote !'),
  ),
  body: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Color(0xff263238),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          abc = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 15, 12),
                        child: Text('SomeThing', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          abc = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 15, 12),
                        child: Text('Nothing', textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          abc = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 15, 12),
                        child: Text('Can You do something ?',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                  child: Material(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          abc = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 12, 15, 12),
                        child: Text('Nothing to do !',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }
}
```

Comment: ,Thanq for your great effort . This does what i actually need, but need another help, how to make gesturedetector to showing ripples when clicked

Comment: @PMahto , Sorry buddy, for that you need to use InkWell. and It will works, tested. I have just updated the code, please check once. and if it works, please upvote me.

Comment: it works, thank again , but sorry , not enough reputation to vote

Comment: I think its a stateless widget , so setState showing error ?

Comment: make it statefull, you work in stateless, i did statefull

Comment: ok ! according to my project setState not required, so i removed setState

Comment: Ow, really sorry, setstate has no activity here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add `Align()` and set `alignment : Alignment.centerLeft` before widget child text

Comment: it will increase the button size

Comment: @DanarPutra ,even is right it increases my button size like (width as match parent ha ha )